# "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed" error vcd::mosaic

Tags: r

```
> library(vcd)
Loading required package: MASS
Loading required package: grid
Loading required package: colorspace
> library(MASS)
> tbl = table(survey$W.Hnd,survey$Fold)
> print(tbl)

        L on R Neither R on L
  Left      10       1      7
  Right     88      17    113
> mosaic(tbl)
Error in if (split_vertical[i]) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
Calls: mosaic -> mosaic.default -> strucplot -> labeling
Execution halted
```

Why am I getting this error, and how to fix the code?

---

Easy paste code here:

```
library(vcd)
library(MASS)
tbl = table(survey$W.Hnd,survey$Fold) # survey is a library data set in MASS
print(tbl)
mosaic(tbl) # produces the above error
```

Comment: A reproducible example would be easier to answer the question. You can also take a look at the `mosaicplot` function.

Comment: @juba Don't you get same error when you run above code? It is supposed to be a reproducible example. (survey is a dataset in MASS library)

Comment: @yasar11732 Sorry, my bad ! `survey` is such a generic name I didn't think it could be a library dataset...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
> mosaic(survey$W.Hnd ~ survey$Fold)
```

[image: moasic]

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use `structable` from the `vcd` package itself.

```
library(vcd)
library(MASS)
tbl <- structable(survey$W.Hnd ~ survey$Fold)
print(tbl)
mosaic(tbl)
```